# Data Set Error in C#

Tags: c#

I am experiencing an error in adp.Fill(ds, "Products"); saying

> "Incorrect syntax near '='.

How can i solve it?

Here is my codes:

```
private void GetRecords(string productID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CategoryCode, PurchasePrice, " +
                        "SellingPrice, Description, Quantity, ProdStatusCode FROM Products" +
                        "WHERE ProductID = " + productID;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds, "Products");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error over there:

**A quick fix:**

```
string cmdstr = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CategoryCode, PurchasePrice, " +
                " SellingPrice, Description, Quantity, ProdStatusCode FROM Products" +
                " WHERE ProductID = '" + productID + "'"
```

**A Smart fix:**

The given code will opens a wide door for sqlInjection. so i prefer you to use parameterized queries instead for this:

```
string cmdstr = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CategoryCode, PurchasePrice, " +
                " SellingPrice, Description, Quantity, ProdStatusCode FROM Products" +
                " WHERE ProductID =@productID"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@productID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productID;  
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(ds, "Products");
```

Comment: there is same error again when i run the program that you suggested.

Comment: it say the same error which is "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: is this you are using `" WHERE ProductID = '" + productID + "'"` there is no `;` after `productID `

Comment: i don't know how to parameterized the queries. can you show it to me how?